# File upload issues phonegap app to Amazon s3

Tags: android, cordova, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm getting JAVA.io.IOException received server error. below is the code to upload file to amazon s3 from phonegap app.

I'm following example from this link:

http://coenraets.org/blog/2013/09/how-to-upload-pictures-from-a-phonegap-app-to-amazon-s3/

var s3Uploader = (function () {

```
var s3URI = encodeURI("http://***********.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/");
    policyBase64 = "base64 string removed";
    signature = "base64 string removed";
    awsKey = 'AWSAccessKeyId removed';
    acl = "public-read";

function upload(imageURI, fileName) {

    var deferred = $.Deferred()

    var ft = new FileTransfer();
        options = new FileUploadOptions();

    options.fileKey = "file";
    options.fileName = fileName;
    options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
    options.chunkedMode = true;
    options.params = {
        "key": fileName,
        "AWSAccessKeyId": awsKey,
        "acl": acl,
        "policy": policyBase64,
        "signature": signature,
        "Content-Type": "image/jpeg"
    };
    ft.upload(imageURI, s3URI,
        function (e) {
        console.log(e);   
     deferred.resolve(e);
        },
        function (e) {
         console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
         deferred.reject(e);
        }, options);

    return deferred.promise();

}

return {
    upload: upload
}
```

}());

var $img = $('img', '.scroller');

```
    takePicture = function (e) {
        var options = {
            quality: 45,
            targetWidth: 1000,
            targetHeight: 1000,
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
            encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
            sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
        };

        navigator.camera.getPicture(
            function (imageURI) {
             alert(imageURI);
             alert(imageURI);
                $img.attr('src', imageURI);
                var fileName = "" + (new Date()).getTime() + ".jpg"; 
                s3Uploader.upload(imageURI, fileName)
                    .done(function () {
                        alert("S3 upload succeeded");
                    })
                    .fail(function () {
                        alert("S3 upload failed");
                    });
            },
            function (message) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(message));
            }, options);

        return false;

    };

$('.camera-btn').on('click', takePicture);
```